# Remove blank line generated due to comments in restructured text

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am writing documentation in RST and generating HTML using Sphinx.

I want to comment out some text but the HTML is inserting a blank line.

```
* Line1
.. * Line2
* Line3
* Line4
```

The HTML prints a blank line between Line1 and Line3. How do I remove this blank line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reST is faulty as it is missing blank lines. Besides, you should indent the comment to avoid ending the list and then start a new one.

```
* Line1

  .. * Line2

* Line3
* Line4
```

Answer (score 0):

@user4184837's answer helped me to figure out a nice hack to comment out, for example, parameter descriptions in a function without breaking the output layout.

Below is an example this method that abuses the [`:meta:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists) fields of reST field lists.

---

Original documentation version.

```
.. py:function:: func(arg1, arg2, opt1=True, opt2=False)

    func description.

    :param arg1: first argument description
    :param arg2: second argument description
    :param opt1: an optional parameter
    :param opt2: another optional parameter
    :returns: the result
```

Same documentation with parameter `opt2` removed and its description commented out, and a `replace` directive inserted between the `param` fields.

```
.. py:function:: func(arg1, arg2, opt1=True)

    func description.

    :param arg1: first |desc|
    :param arg2: second |desc|
    :meta:
        .. |desc| replace:: argument description
    :param opt1: an optional parameter
    :meta param opt2: another optional parameter
    :returns: the result
```

This can also be achieved using Google-style documentation with the Sphinx extension `napoleon`, but the `:meta:` fields must be moved to after the Args/Parameters block. Even though, using these still preserves the spacing between the blocks (e.g. between Args and Returns).

```py
def func(arg1, arg2, opt1=True):
    """
    func description.

    Args:
        arg1: first |desc|
        arg2: second |desc|
        opt1: an optional parameter
    :meta _ opt2: another optional parameter
    :meta:
        .. |desc| replace:: argument description

    Returns:
        The result.
    """
```